# jar file gets corrupted while building with maven

Tags: java, maven-plugin, maven-3

while building a war file i am copying a set of jars from a location to a folder inside the war. While the files do get copied , however i think they get corrupted because the same class files of the jar when taken outside the war opens with a debugger while it does not open after taking from war file .

This is a part of my war pom.xml where i  copy the jars

```
<execution> 
    <id>copy-jars</id> 
    <phase>process-resources</phase> 
    <goals> 
        <goal>copy-resources</goal> 
    </goals> 
    <configuration> 
        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/${project.artifactId}-${buildNumber}/somefolder</outputDirectory> 
         <resources> 
            <resource> 
                <directory>SomeSourceDirectory</directory> 
                <filtering>true</filtering> 
                <includes> 
                    <include>**/**</include> 
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources> 
    </configuration> 
</execution>
```

*SomeSourceDirectory* has some jars and some other files
The result is:
myWar/somefolder/a.jar   but when i open the classes inside this jar in a debugger..i get error in WinZip that

```
Invalid compressed data to extract.
Severe Error:  Compressed data is invalid
```

However the same class file can be viewed when i view it in original folder i.e outside the war.
So is there a mistake while copying the jars?
Thanks.

Comment: Are the jars the same? Same filesize, maybe same md5 checksum...

Comment: the filesize is the same however md5 checksum seems different..i checked with md5.jar downlaoded from http://activityworkshop.net/software/md5/index.html  ..can't understand why different checksums ??

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Remove `<filtering>true</filtering>`, it corrupts the jar files.

Comment: great! thanks a lot Emmanuel ..that worked :)  but still wondering  why does maven has this wierd behaviour?? Why is filtering useful then?

Comment: Filtering is useful when you copy text resources containing references to the project version for example. Applied on binary files it will corrupt the content.

Comment: when using the assembly plugin be aware that this setting might not be in the pom.xml, but in the associated descriptor xml file

Comment: Important note here, the default for the maven-resources-plugin appears to be "true" for filtering, so I needed to explicitly set filtering to "false", not just remove the line

Answer (score 17):

Also, you can continue benefit to use maven filtering without corrupting jars inside.

We choose to exclude jar from filtered extensions.

In th pluginManagement section of the parent pom we put this configuration

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <configuration>
      <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
      <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
        <nonFilteredFileExtension>jar</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        <nonFilteredFileExtension>pdf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        <nonFilteredFileExtension>swf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        <nonFilteredFileExtension>zip</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        <nonFilteredFileExtension>bz2</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        <nonFilteredFileExtension>gz</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        <nonFilteredFileExtension>acp</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        <nonFilteredFileExtension>bin</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        <nonFilteredFileExtension>odt</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        <nonFilteredFileExtension>doc</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        <nonFilteredFileExtension>xls</nonFilteredFileExtension>
      </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Note we added jar extensions as well as default maven excluded filetypes (its a zip after all).

Besides avoiding corruption of the archive it also speeds up the process as it does not have to filter large files.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/). It's my favourite plugin to add custom resources to a *.war file. See also [Pre-defined Descriptor Files](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error when I've added

```
<copy ...>
<fileset ... />
<filterchain>
    <tokenfilter>
         <replacestring from="..." to="..." />
    </tokenfilter>
</filterchain>
</copy>
```

to my copy task in ANT. It corrupted the jar files when copying them.
I've solved this by applying the filter ONLY on the targeted text files and not on jar files.

Comment: I have the same issue with antrun plugin: can you please explain how to solve that problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just as addition to the other answers, the other option is to enable the filtering only for the resources that require filtering:

```
<build>
...
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>core.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>pdf/color_profile/sRGB.icc</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was there were **multiple spaces & new-line** in-between the **ClassPaths**. Had to make it 1 space separated. Checked it through jd-gui

[image: Space in Classpath in Manifest file]