# invalid CEN header (bad signature)

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I haven't worked on Java much but I am trying to upgrade the libabry. I am trying to run java google app engine project locally using maven and I am getting the error/warning message (listed below).

```
2018-05-17 14:39:55.050:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.3.18.v20170406
2018-05-17 14:39:55.189:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context c.g.a.t.d.j.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@7995092a{/,file:///Users/user1/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/helloworld/,null}{/Users/asingh1/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/sap_gateway}
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid CEN header (bad signature)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:103)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:93)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:69)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:84)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:89)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration.getTlds(MetaInfConfiguration.java:409)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration.scanForTlds(MetaInfConfiguration.java:326)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration.scanJars(MetaInfConfiguration.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration.preConfigure(MetaInfConfiguration.java:94)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:485)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:521)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:422)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:389)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:346)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:284)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:87)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:105)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:274)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:219)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:217)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:368)
at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:45)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:223)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:214)
2018-05-17 14:39:55.201:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started NetworkTrafficSelectChannelConnector@43ee72e6{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{localhost:8080}
2018-05-17 14:39:55.212:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @1089ms
May 17, 2018 6:39:55 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService startHotDeployScanner
```

INFO: Full scan of the web app in place every 1s.

Java Version: jdk1.8.0_172
Maven version: 3.5.3
appengine.target.version: 1.9.63
maven-compiler-plugin: 3.7.0 (source and target:1.8)
javax.servlet-api: 4.0.1

I have tried to remove .m2 folder and mvn clean install

Any help is appreciated!
Thank you.

Comment: Some JAR file is certainly corrupted. It might be one of the JARs of you project. Might be a remote one. I don't know.

Anyway, I see from the log that you tried this in Eclipse. Can you do "mvn clean appengine:run" on the command line and see if you get the exact same error?

Comment: If you debug from within Eclipse, you can add an _exception breakpoint_ from the _Breakpoints_ view on `java.util.zip.ZipException` to identify the zip file in question.

Comment: Note that App Engine standard for Java 8 only supports the Servlet 3.1 APIs, and does not support Servlet 4.x.

Comment: There are two possible things causing an issue here. As mentioned before one of the JAR files could be corrupted, did you try what Chanseok Oh suggested? Another one would be the type of zip file, try to locate the zip file as Brian de Alwis suggested and let us know what type the zip file is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you all for the help! The JAR file was fine on the source. I ran `jarsigner verify` on the source file I got unsigned message. When I ran the same command on the JAR file in the target folder, I got "invalid CEN header (bad signature)". Then I searched for JAR file corrupted during mvn build and then found the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797831/jar-file-gets-corrupted-while-building-with-maven). The file was corrupted during mvn build process. I removed `<filtering>true</filtering>` from the pom.xml file and I stopped getting the error message.