# Unable to display a PDF file in Angular app

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have a PDF file stored in a directory within the application (`assets/pdf/fileName.pdf`). I need to display it on a new tab on a button click from a dialog.

Here is what I have, after looking at various answers:

In *.component.ts:

```
  openPDF() {
    this.myService.fetchPDF().subscribe(
      res => {
        let file = new window.Blob([res], {type: 'application/pdf'});
        let fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
        window.open(fileURL, '_blank');
      }
    );
  }
```

In *.service.ts:

```
  fetchPDF(): any {
    const path = 'assets/pdf/fileName.pdf';
    return this.httpClient.get(PathResolver.resolveStatic(path),{responseType : 'blob'});
  }
```

I already tried using `responseType : 'arraybuffer'`, but it didn't work out either.

Here are the threads I have looked at:

- [How to Display blob (.pdf) in an AngularJS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628378/how-to-display-blob-pdf-in-an-angularjs-app)
- [Angular 2 download PDF from API and Display it in View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35368633/angular-2-download-pdf-from-api-and-display-it-in-view)
- [PDF Blob - Pop up window not showing content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729451/pdf-blob-pop-up-window-not-showing-content)
- [Failed to load PDF document - Angular JS - BLOB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28093736/failed-to-load-pdf-document-angular-js-blob)

Comment: What is the outcome of your current code?

Comment: @amanpurohit: On Chrome, the new tab opens and closes right away. On Firefox, I was able to see the error saying something along the line of the PDF file is corrupted or invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why are you using `httpClient`. The outcome that you want could be simply achieved by the following code

In *.service.ts:

```
fetchPDF(): any {
  const path = 'assets/pdf/fileName.pdf'
  return path;
}
```

In *.component.ts:

```
openPDF() {
  window.open(this.myService.fetchPDF(), '_blank');
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion with different PDF files, but on Firefox, all of them got a 304 response code, whilst on Chrome, they showed the "failed to load" error.

Comment: I looked at the "target" folder after doing a local maven build. It seems like the pdf file is somehow malformed. It's just a blank document when I opened it. Any idea why?

Comment: It turns out the maven build corrupted the `.pdf` file. I followed the instruction in this answer and the pdf file being rendered just fine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16088835/4570571

Answer (score 0):

You will either need to use the html embed tag (most likely also using a safe pipe), a PDF viewer (like Google PDF Viewer) or you can open the PDF in a new tab (this is the more common approach I see).  It depends on your preference.

Comment: My intention is to display the PDF in a new tab. Do you have any suggestions to modify my existing code?

Comment: Drop it in an <a> tag with a _blank attribute

```html
<a _blank href="/path/to/your/file.pdf">Open My PDF In New Tab</a>
```